# Combining Multiple Random Forest Models from Amelia Imputed Data

Tags: r, random-forest, r-zelig

I just created 40 imputed data sets using the Amelia package, and they are stored in a.out.

I then used the lapply function to create randomforest models on the data sets:

```
rf.amelia.out = lapply(a.out$imputations, function(i) randomForest(y + x1+x2, data = i) )
```

Now I would like to combine these models to make a prediction on a bunch a.test.out, which is a list of amelia imputed data testing data.

I can't figure out how to combine these random forest models. I've tried randomforest combine function like `combine(rf.amelia.out)` but that didn't work. The problem is that `rf.amelia.out` is not a model object, but neither is `rf.amelia.out[1]`.

I also tried to use zelig to automatically combine multiple models:

```
rf.z.out = zelig(y~x1+x2, data = a.out, model = "rf")
```

But I don't think zelig supports random forest models.

How do I access and combine the multiple random forest models so that I can make one prediction?

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?

Comment: Hi Mike, Thank you for your answer below. It worked perfectly. Sorry for the late response - first time on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @user1888582 When an answer works, you should "accept" it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

Since `rf.amelia.out` is already a list, the `combine` function in `randomForest` loses its methods when it tries to convert it to a list again. I recommend one of two fixes:

1. Change the `combine` function and then use the modified version:

   `body(combine)[[4]] <- substitute(rflist <- (...))`

   `rf.all <- combine(rf.amelia.out)`
2. Or use:

   `combine(rf.amelia.out[[1]].rf.amelia.out[[2]],...)`

I think the first way is easier (and much less manual).